# Show that there does not exist integers $n_{1}, \ldots, n_{8}$, not necessarily distinct, such that $n_{1}^{4}+\cdots+n_{8}^{4}=1993$.

Tags: number-theory

I tried using mod of $8$ and got that mod $8$  of an even number raised to the power $4$ is $0$, and $1$ in case of odd number. Also, $1993$ is $1$ mod $8$, but can't make progress from this point. Also, can't figure out what to do with the information that they aren't necessarily distinct.

Comment: Try modulo $16$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea, but using modulo $16$ instead works better (as also suggested in [Arturo Magidin's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452029/show-that-there-does-not-exist-integers-n-1-ldots-n-8-not-necessarily#comment9323943_4452029)). Similar to modulo $8$, in modulo $16$, every even number raised to the power $4$ is $0$, and is $1$ for odd numbers. This means the left side sum can only be a value between $0$ and $8$, inclusive, modulo $16$. However, $1993 \equiv 9 \pmod{16}$, which proves there are no integers $n_{1}, \ldots, n_{8}$ that solve the equation.

As for these integers not necessarily being distinct, the requirement doesn't make any difference with this proof. I suspect it's likely mentioned in your problem just to keep it as general as possible (i.e., so we can't exclude possible solutions just because any of the $x_i$ values are repeated) in case a different approach is attempted instead, e.g., if some form of brute force was tried. Also, if they were required to be distinct instead, then since $8^4 = 4096$, we have $|n_i| \le 6$. However, using modulo $8$ as you did, there needs to be $7$ even integers among the $n_i$, but $n_i \in \{-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6\}$ which has $7$ elements. Thus, each integer in that set must be used exactly once, but $(-6)^4 + 6^4 = 2592$, so there would be no solutions.

Comment: Ah i get it now, but how did you come up with mod 16 specifically? Did you keep trying with some others until you came up with mod 16? What was your thought process behind it?

Comment: @OlympiadRunner As $(2n)^4 = 16n^4$, meaning modulo $16$ is the highest value where all even numbers are congruent to $0$, it's worth checking. However, it's only useful if the odd integers have a small set of possible values &, fortunately, it's just $1$ modulo $16$. If you didn't already know this, it's relatively easy to verify manually but it's easier to use what you noted, i.e., for every integer $n$, there's $k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ where $(2n+1)^2 = 8k + 1$. Then $(2n+1)^4 = ((2n+1)^2)^2 = (8k+1)^2 = 64k^2+16k+1 = 16k(4k+1)+1$. Finally, there's of course $1993 \equiv 9 \pmod{16}$.

Comment: @OlympiadRunner Also, every odd integer raised to the $2^{n-2}$th power is congruent to one modulo $2^n$ for $n\gt2$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-You have $n^4\equiv0\pmod{16}$ when $n$ is even and $n^4\equiv1\pmod{16}$ when $n$ is odd then taking modulo $16$ you have $ n_{1}^{4}+\cdots+n_{8}^{4}\le8$.
But $1993\equiv 9\pmod{16}$